# Bing image search api - nonsense results

Tags: c#, image, bing-api

I've made a simple script to pull images from the image search api.
If I give it a search term of 'a puppy' then I get puppies.
If I give it 'mo farah' then I get a whole range of not mo farah pictures.
It feels like the code is very straight forward, but I must be missing something.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?
[image: Weird results]

```
public async Task CallBing(string queryTerm, int count, string aspect = "All", string size = "Large", string color = "ColorOnly", string license = "Public")
        {
            queryTerm = queryTerm.Replace(" ", "+");
           
            // Replace with your Bing Image API key
            var apiUrl = $"https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/images/search?q={queryTerm}"
            //imageType
            + $"&count={count}" // Limit the number of results to 10
            + $"&imageType=Photo"
            + $"&mkt=en-us"            
            + $"&aspect={aspect}" // Limit the results to square images
            + $"&size={size}" // Limit the results to medium-sized images
            + $"&color={color}" // Limit the results to color images only
            + $"&license={license}"; // Limit the results to images with public licenses

            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", apiKey);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-MSEdge-ClientIP", "999.999.999.999");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Search-Location", "lat:47.60357;long:-122.3295;re:100");

                    var response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<BingImageResult>(content);
                        int i = 0;
                        foreach (var image in result.value)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(image.contentUrl);

                            using (WebClient dlclient = new WebClient())
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    dlclient.DownloadFile(new Uri(image.contentUrl), @$"c:\temp\bings\{i}.jpg");
                                }
                                catch (Exception dlEx)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine($"Error Downloading image {dlEx.Message}");
                                }
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Failed to retrieve images: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                // throw;
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Simple rest example based on Microsofts own code

Comment: Given Mo Farah is an athlete I see no problem with the first results.

Comment: It may not be your code.  The search engine may be return all results when nothing matches the search.  Try doing search manually with Bing and see what results you get.  I do not use Bing and prefer Chrome.  I keep on disabling Bing on my machine but every time a new Windows update occurs Bing get enabled as the default.

Comment: If you go to the actual Bing Image Search and set all those same filters as in the code, you get a similar result. Specifically setting license type to Public understandably filters out most pictures showing Mo Farah because those would be typically from newspapers and image banks that don't have a public domain license.

Comment: If you used the license "public domain" as the comments in your code suggest then I can confirm none of the images returned by Bing are picturing Mo Farah. You can verify this yourself by going to https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=mo+farah&qft=+filterui:license-L1&form=IRFLTR&first=1

Comment: @GuyIncognito and rene Thank you very much for your answers.  Indeed removing the public flag returned sensible results.